# Conditional arguments  WP_Query for post custom fields

Tags: wp-query

All in my case I want to get post result by Gender, Age, City etc...
I am using this query. If i have any of variable like age, city, gender for that "AND" operation will perform and get only result for that variable.

**Note:** Consider those case also where i have no variable like city but it should work for gender & state.

My Query is

```
$gender = $_GET['gender'];
                $city = $_GET['city'];
                $state = $_GET['state'];

                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'post_type' => 'profile',
                    'meta_query' => array( 
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array('meta_key' => 'wpcf-gender', 'meta_value' => $_GET['gender'], 'meta_compare' => '=='),
                            array('meta_key' => 'wpcf-city', 'meta_value' => $_GET['city'], 'meta_compare' => '=='),
                            array('meta_key' => 'wpcf-state', 'meta_value' => $_GET['state'], 'meta_compare' => '==')                           
                        ),
                    'paged' => $paged ) 
                );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code where you can add the meta query if certain $GET keys are set.

```
$query_array = array('relation' => 'AND');

if(isset($_GET['gender']) && !empty($_GET['gender'])){
    $gender = $_GET['gender'];
    array_push($query_array, array('key' => 'wpcf-gender', 'value' => $gender, 'compare' => '='));
}
if(isset($_GET['city']) && !empty($_GET['city'])){
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    array_push($query_array, array('key' => 'wpcf-city', 'value' => $city, 'compare' => '='));
}

if(isset($_GET['state']) && !empty($_GET['state'])){
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    array_push($query_array, array('key' => 'wpcf-state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => '='));
}

                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                    'post_type' => 'profile',
                    //'query' => $query_array, should be 'meta_query' => $query_array,
                    'meta_query' => $query_array,
                    'paged' => $paged ) 
                );
```

**Reference:**

`array_push()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: I don't know but it displaying all records... Have look at http://demo.digi-corp.com:82/jeevansrishti/search-me/?gender=Male&state=&city=&age=

Comment: try to use `=` for meta compare instead of `==`

Answer (score -1):

```
'query' => $query_array,
```

should be

```
'meta_query' => $query_array,
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Could you provide an explanation on how this solves their problem?